# Need help figuring out how to add data customer and billing data to stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I implemented stripe their docs is kind of confusing but I got it to work. What I need help now is passing billing and customer info to stripe.I do not know where to add the address.

I tried to do it like below by putting address in PaymentIntent
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0bHR.jpg

```
// Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
            $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                'amount' => Cart::total(2, '.', '') * 100,
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'automatic_payment_methods' => [
                    'enabled' => true,
                ],
            ]);
```

My flow is shipping address > billing address > payment

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    

<script defer>
        const stripe_key = 'pk_test_51IX6wjDNgrti9hItzFXHGdxF32r6lQDsQJa1KI6746HgnnJEVY7XbX0a7o9fSFuGeWzZTcAzJXNuSFzekqmWSroO00QFB9NpUn';
        const payment_intent_route = 'https://jewelrycadfiles.com/payment/intent';
        const _token = 'UE5r6J5c7hhLLpFjMrA2hCmeZ4YuG2LECPAu7SJu';
        const place_order_route = 'https://jewelrycadfiles.com/checkout';
        const order_cancel_route = 'https://jewelrycadfiles.com/payment/cancel';
        const finish_page = 'https://jewelrycadfiles.com/payment/finished';
        const buy_now_mode = '0';
    </script>
```

Comment: How are you collecting payment information?  Are you using the Payment Element?  The Card Element?  Something else?

Comment: @JustinMichael yes payment element

Answer (score 0):

With the Payment Element, [when you call `confirmPayment()` you can pass in `billing_details`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-confirmParams-payment_method_data-billing_details).

For example:

```js
stripe.confirmPayment({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    return_url: 'https://example.com',
  },
  billing_details: {
    name: 'Alex Smith',
    address: { ... },
  }
}).then(...);
```

Comment: the thing im trying to accomplish is to avoid having the payment element ask for the customer zip code. I collect their address before hand so I can pass it before payment element loads the card form

Comment: I thought it made more sense and allows for more secure payments to pass the billing address prior to payment

Comment: When you create the Payment Element you can specify `defaultValues`, including the billing address info, if you've already collected it: https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-defaultValues